# How to get the source of URL in Javascript that calls on Javascript to open the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm relatively new to Javascript, but I am coming across a problem. I am trying to create an iframe on my page that then takes the source from a link and displays it in the iframe. The problem is the source is only giving a "javascript:" as the link, with an id. I use `setAttribute` with src, but I have no idea how to pull the url from the link "javascript:"

When I look at the source from the link I get 
    `a id="idhere" href="javascript:`

The code I have so far looks like this, but I am baffled what to do next...

```
frame = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
frame.setAttribute("src", notsurehowtocallurlwithinthejavascript:here);
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```

Any advice??

Updated code I found.

```
$( function() { $("#xl_idhere").click( function() { var zz = "http://www.link.com" ; window.open(zz); }); });
```

How to get this to appear in iframe? Want to pull the link from it.

Comment: What does the link html look like? If this is on a page you don't control the code on it is probably not possible

Comment: If the src value is javasript:void(0) or something like that. That means there's probably some javascript click event handler that handles changing the src value.

Comment: I looked at the frame source and found this at the bottom, I assume this is exactly what I am looking for.

Updated main question with the xtra code I found.

How would I call that into the iframe now and get it to appear?